# Insert new options from Chosen plugin into mySQL with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, insert, jquery-chosen

I'm using a Chosen plugin to create a `select` that can dynamically add a new `option` if a searched one is not found. Said `select` fetches data from mySQL table (1 column) and inserts them into the `select` as `option` (`inc/topicselect.inc.php` file).

To add a new `option` inside the `select` I'm using javascript code inside `chosen.jquery.js` below (case 13) hooked to Enter key. Now, this works perfectly but only inserts it into `select` temporarily, meaning that after a refresh, it's all gone.

What I'm trying to achieve, is to get that newly added `option` and insert it into a table using PHP (the last code snippet), so that it'll show permanently to all users later on using that (working) fetch from earlier.

Any ideas on how I can bridge that javascript with PHP insert?

```html
<select data-placeholder="Wybierz tematy:" class="topic-dropdown" name="topic" action="inc/topicselect.inc.php" class="chosen-select" multiple>
  <?php require 'inc/topicselect.inc.php' ?>
</select>
```

```js
case 13:
  evt.preventDefault();
  if (this.results_showing) {
    if (!this.is_multiple || this.result_highlight) {
      return this.result_select(evt);
    }
    $(".topic-dropdown").append('<option>' + $(evt.target).val() + '</option>');
    $(".topic-dropdown").trigger('chosen:updated');
    this.result_highlight = this.search_results.find('li.active-result').lastreturn;
    this.result_select(evt);
  }
  break;
```

```css
<?php if(isset($_POST["?"])) {
  require "connect.inc.php";
  $topic=$_POST["topicname"];
  if(empty($topic)) {
    header("Location: ../index.php#dodajpost?puste");
    exit();
  }
  else {
    $sql="SELECT name FROM topics WHERE name=?";
    $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      header("Location: ../index.php#dodajpost?error=sqlerror");
      exit();
    }
    else {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_POST["topicname"]);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
      $resultcheck=mysqli_stmt_num_rows();
      if($resultcheck > 0) {
        header("Location: ../index.php#dodajpost?jużjest");
        exit();
      }
      else {
        $sql="INSERT INTO topics (name) VALUES (?)";
        $stmt=mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
        if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
          header("Location: ../index.php#dodajpost?błądzapisu");
          exit();
        }
        else {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_POST["topicname"]);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          header("Location: ../index.php#dodajpost");
          exit();
        }
      }
    }
  }
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  mysqli_close($conn);
}

else {
  header("Location: ../index.php#dodajpost?errorstart");
  exit();
}

?>
```

Comment: You don't want to insert, you want to mark whatever is searched on with a flag ( like a boolean ) then you can tell on page load by that flag what was searched before.  So when you get the results, you need to also run an update with the same where as the select that will trip it from a 0 to a 1

Comment: So just before you return your results (When you know it's a success) do `$sql="UPDATE  topics SET someflag=1 WHERE name=?";`  Then when you do the initial build of the options, you can look for that flag.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and ideally should not be used in new code.